# Is there a way to index multiple sites at once on google

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing

I have a site with 60 subdomains. I was wondering if there was a way to index each of the subdomans seperately but quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Subdomains are considered part of the main website so as far as Google is concerned there is nothing special about them. As far as getting your content indexed by Google quickly, you don't have any real control over that either. Google decides how fast it will crawl and index new content. Sites that are updated frequently and have a lot of high quality links pointing to them will see their pages indexed quickly. This site expereiences such things. Sites like yours that are new and lacking high quality links and may not be updating frequenetly, will see that it takes longer for Google to crawl and index their content.

So the best you can do is keep adding quality content to your site and seek high quality links to your pages.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a [sitemap](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) for each subdomain will help Google find and index your pages.  However, you do need separate sitemaps for each subdomain, since the [sitemap protocol spec](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) says that each sitemap file may only contain URLs from one site.

If you don't feel like submitting 60 sitemaps manually, the following method should work:

1. Create a sitemap for each subdomain and place them all under the parent domain.  (This is necessary for step 3.)
2. In the [robots.txt file](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) for each subdomain, include a [`Sitemap:` directive](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_robots) pointing to the sitemap for that subdomain.  This is important, since [it lets Google know that the sitemap is authoritative for that subdomain](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#sitemaps_cross_submits) even though it's located elsewhere.
3. Create a single [sitemap index file](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index) listing all the sitemaps and submit it to Google.

Of course, you also need to remember to keep the sitemaps up to date as you add new pages to your sites.